# Typescript, I'm curious if it can implement this dynamic type checking

Tags: typescript

It seems a little out of the ordinary.

```js
interface APIS {
  user: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  },
  job: {
    address: string;
    company: string;
  }
}

type Keys = keyof APIS;

/**
 * params: key in Keys + '/' + k in keyof APIS[key]
 */
function getSomething(params: string) {
  //
}

getSomething('user/name');     // yes
getSomething('user/age');      // yes
getSomething('job/address');   // yes
getSomething('job/company');   // yes


getSomething('job/name');      // no
getSomething('user/address');  // no
```

params is a concatenated string, Typescript can do type checking?
Who can provide an idea can also ?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you'd like to be able to specify that `getSomething` only takes a string which is a valid value of `APIS` represented as `key/key`etc.?

Comment: Typescript is pure JavaScript with types. Typescript won't do anything extra like type checking and similar stuff.

Comment: @JoséCabo typescript won't do type checking? Could you elaborate? I thought that's exactly what it would do

Comment: @OliverRadini yes, like this: k1/k2, k1: user or job. If k1 is user, k2 can only be name or age etc.

Comment: @JoséCabo If so, it would be a great disappointment. I found some third libraries that use this form.
Like this:
```
dispatch({ type: 'namespace/property' })
```

Comment: @fanzkday which libraries are able to do that?

Comment: @fanzkday I don't see why it's disappointment. It seems you're having incorrect expectations. As I said, typescript won't do type checking during runtime. It's not part of what's expected from Typescript. By looking at your question, a possible solution would be to have function that "parses" a string and treats it as a path for the given object. You'd need a library or develop a solution that does that. Look into xpath or json-path type libraries.

Comment: IMO, the right solution depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. If it's object validation, there are other solutions (e.g. json schema validation). Maybe you don't need to do that at all! I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this generically with a `path` function:

```js
interface APIS {
  user: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  },
  job: {
    address: string;
    company: string;
  }
}

const x: APIS = {
  user: {
    name: "n",
    age: 1,
  },
  job: {
    address: "add",
    company: "c"
  }
}

const path2 = <T, K1 extends keyof T>(k1: K1, k2: keyof T[K1], o: T) => o[k1][k2];

console.log(path2('user', 'name', x))
```

But I believe you have to write separate functions for each 'depth' of path, as you need to be able to specify a generic for each. I'm guessing that that there may be a way to get around this (but I can't think of it right now).

I'd suggest you'd be better thinking of ways to further break down what it is you're trying to do:

```js
const path = <T>(p: keyof T) => (x: T) => x[p];

const compose2 = <T, U, V>(
    f: (x: U) => V,
    g: (x: T) => U,
) => (x: T) => f(g(x));


interface APIS {
  user: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  },
  job: {
    address: string;
    company: string;
  }
}

const x: APIS = {
    user: {
        name: "n",
        age: 1,
    },
    job: {
        address: "add",
        company: "c"
    }
};

const getName = compose2(path('name'), path('user'));
const getCompany = compose2(path('company'), path('job'));

const testA = getName(x);
const testB = getCompany(x);

console.log(testA);
console.log(testB);
```

However in terms of what you'd actually like to do; you're talking about Typescript being able to parse concatenated string literal types; it seems that this is not possible ([see this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754)). There's a lot of interest, but doesn't seem like much in the way of a solution yet.

Comment: Thanks, It would be nice if TSC server supported plugins.

Comment: @fanzkday that'd be interesting - though I think at this point people would potentially like to see this in standard typescript, if someone could implement it.